# Flutter force higher package dependency version

Tags: flutter, version, versioning, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages

TLDR: How to **force a specific** Flutter **package** (library) **version** for the entire app?

Let's suppose I have the following dependencies in my `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  datetime_picker_formfield: 0.4.3
  date_utils: 0.1.0+3
  intl: 0.15.8
```

which gives me a version conflict error:

```
Because flutter_app depends on date_utils 0.1.0+3 
which depends on intl ^0.16.0, intl ^0.16.0 is required.
```

but when we change intl to `intl: 0.15.8` we get:

```
Because flutter_app depends on datetime_picker_formfield 0.4.3 
which depends on intl ^0.15.8, intl ^0.15.8 is required.
```

How to force `intl: 0.16.0` for both: `datetime_picker_formfield` and `date_utils` packages?

Answer (score 14):

Use `dependency_overrides` to force a specific package version for the entire Flutter app.

```
dependency_overrides:
  intl: 0.16.0
```

So we get:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  datetime_picker_formfield: 0.4.3
  date_utils: 0.1.0+3
  intl: 0.16.0
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dependency_overrides:
  intl: 0.16.0
```